# Add a Liferay portlet into an HTML code of my own portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i want to put a predefined portlet from code (like Album, Document Library, Calendar, etc) into my own jsp portlet. I have some HTML code and for example I wanna put it inside a "div" or "td" tag.

I've been searching and there is no results of this topic.

So I dont know even if this is allowed with Liferay's portlets or what.

Thanks!

Comment: @MartinGamulin can u help me in my prob...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747253/adding-custom-methods-in-hook-environment/9753001#9753001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too simple, but you might want to look at a portlet called NestedPortlet that does exactly that and inspect it. Also, [Bert Willems has written a nice article](http://www.devatwork.nl/2011/07/liferay-embedding-portlets-in-your-portlet/) about this topic.

Comment: mmmm the Bert's solution seems the best for my problem... Thanks!

Comment: Above given link is not opening for me, please share the alternative or new link path

Comment: That link is from 2011, so quite outdated. You can still find the article here: https://web.archive.org/web/20110820153831/http://www.devatwork.nl/ but chances are that this ancient answer won't really help today (or if it does, there might be better solutions). In fact, there might be better solutions to your problem than embedding a portlet. Quite often I've seen it to signal an x-y problem, where the actual solution was a lot better (and completely different)